# Free animated character models for my first Unity game

Tags: unity

I am creating my first game in Unity for my intra-college game development competition. A hack and slash type of game. It's about a warrior who is escaping from a prison. Setting is medieval times.
Thing is, I am looking for 3 free (low poly) animated character models which are appropriate for this game.
1. The hero (has a sword, with optional shield)
2. Basic enemy guard (with sword/ hammer/ other melee weapon, no shields)
3. Boss (with melee weapon)
I searched for the above over the last couple of days, but couldn't find them.

My modeling skills are not such that I can create my own character models. However I have managed to create the game levels.
Now I am looking for some help with the character models.

Can anyone please link me to the appropriate free models?

Last date of game submission is March 8. So I need the models urgently. Please help.

P.S.  The game is slightly inspired by Prince of Persia: Warrior Within

Comment: Welcome to GameDev!  Please take a look at our [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq).  Questions asking where free assets can be found are not within the scope.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge I don't really know of any sites that would give 3d models already animated for free, but you might be able to find some for a low price (if you're willing to spend a bit):

first look on the, https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/

then I would go to, http://www.turbosquid.com/

lastly (but still good), http://www.3drt.com/3dm/3dm.htm

And if you still can't find any I would have recommend contacting someone or a site and ask to use some animated models for educational use (not commercial). But since this is time sensitive I think buying them or making them (which would take a lot of time) are the only options.

Edit: I found this haven't had time to go through it properly but it may help in your search, http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-excellent-free-3d-model-websites/

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortunately I cannot afford to buy models at the moment.
By the way, I had already come across the resource at Hongkiat.com. But I didn't find anything suitable for my project. :-(

Comment: there's also Unimations - but the way you download stuff is just ridiculous...